# How to add learnability as value proposition in resume?

Tags: resume, career-development, learning

As a software engineer professional, I used to keep myself updated in latest features of my programming language, new architecture trends, new technologies, etc by listening podcasts, following blogs, technical presentations, etc. I also used to read journals, books, blogs etc. to better understand technology and attend courses to gain new skills. From my past couple of years of experience, I have seen very less engineers who spend some time daily on learning. By doing above mentioned things, I am adding lot of value to my current employer.

How should I write it in my resume to tell future employer?

Comment: Honestly, you prove this by the the things you achieved with what you learned. Anything talking about ability to learn quickly is pretty much ignored because everyone says that and as such it becomes meaningless.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: I guess if I can write something in cover letter then I can put in resume as well. I could be wrong as well.

Comment: @HLGEM: Learning has multiplying factor. There is a difference between voluntary and involuntary learning as there is difference between coding as profession and contributing to open source in free time.

Comment: No there really isn't a difference in business terms. If you learn things that are useful to the business and thus have accomplishments, that is interesting to a manager whether they were voluntary or required by your current job is irrelevant, whether they were open source or not is irrelevant. What matters to the hiring person is what you have done with what you learned not that you studied.

Comment: As one of the founders of this group of sites titled one of his books, "Smart   **and** gets things done" (emphasis mine).  It's not what you know, but what you do with it.

Comment: "Learnability" describes how easy subject matter is to learn. You're trying to claim learning ability. And the way to do so and have it be taken seriously is to show how much you have learned how quickly and how deeply, not claim as an abstract.

Comment: It doesn't look like you understand the difference between a resume and a cover letter. "The difference between your resume and cover letter is that your resume should provide the reader with a better understanding of who you are. Your cover letter should connect the dots for the reader and show how your previous experiences apply to the job for which you are applying." - http://www.temple.edu/provost/careercenter/students/resume-and-cover-letter.html

Comment: @HLGEM: So if learnings has added business value and your current manager appreciates it, is there any way to add focus to it apart from your resume listing those achievements? I could be unlucky but I have met very few engineers who take learnings very seriously. I have seen few companies asking specifically "Do you do something to increase your education or skills every day?"

Comment: Because most companies don't care if you do that. They care if you know how to do your job and can learn things that will be useful in your job or one that you are likely to be competing for.  They don't care if you learn new stuff everyday and they actively dislike it if that takes you away from actually doing your job because you are playing when you should be working. They don't like it if it makes you tired (from doing it on off hours)  affecting performance. Companies most likely to appreciate it are consulting companies where they always need people with a wide variety of skill sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the working world, learning only has value when you can apply it.  If you haven't/can't use it in a project at work, you could build some open source project to show that you have mastered the information and its usage.

Resumes are for achievements, not potential.  As @JoeStrazzere commented, you could include it in your cover letter.  It is also fair game to discuss during an interview to show that you are interested in new technologies and broadening your skills.  But until you demonstrate you can work with what you have learned, it will have very limited value to a potential employer.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. Both the answers discourage me to write it in resume with reasons. I am confused which one to accept as answer. I will wait for some more time.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can show how you've implemented what you learn in projects and more importantly how you were able to change projects for the better, you may be giving the impression that you just read what you like and aren't able to focus on things to help you in your job.

Having a willingness to learn is important in your field. It is assumed developers continue to learn. Not all of them do, so I don't know how beneficial it is to bring attention to how you're better than the lowest programmers. If you find there are areas of technology in a new job, you can use your willingness to stretch your skills as a reason for seeking a new job. Look for ways to insert it in the conversation, but don't list it on your resume.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. Both the answers discourage me to write it in resume with reasons. I am confused which one to accept as answer. I will wait for some more time.